# C# import XML information

Tags: c#, xml, optimization, import

I am fairly new to C# and also don't know must about storing data options.

What I want is a program that display's a tableView,  of customers, with two columns (name,contact), and then when one person is selected it opens a new windows with the rest of the personal information.

I was thinking of using xml file to store data, and when the program starts, the tableView gets populated with all the names and contacts, but when one person is selected I need to search throughout the entire file, and pull the rest of the data.

This seems to me like a very poorly optimized methode, so I was wondering if there is a better solution for this.

Comment: Anything wrong with simply loading all the data on startup? Are you expecting to have so much data that that becomes infeasible?

Comment: Perhaps you should use a [DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It can read/write to/from Xml. And bind it to a DataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to store your data in a database (dB). MS Access is a good beginner dB and Visual Studio supports a visual editor for it. Note: MS Access is not scalable for Enterprise solutions. For professional applications and above you need to use a dB like: SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL, etc or a NoSQL dB.

The advantage of using a dB like MS Access is that there's lots of example code online and many features are baked into Visual Studio to support it, like a visual datagridview (Editor/List) with an easy binding to your dB.

Comment: MS Access - please never recommend that EVER again. Sure MS Access is better than an XML file for customer storage but bahhh its so much better to use a proper RDBMS or NoSQL dB. Not Access.

Comment: 1. i said like ;), i dont really like access but 2. Thats not true. For simple and advanced programms like a login or storing costumer information access is fine. Easy to use , visual editor, easy integration in VS. Access is (fully) supported. I would not recommend a database like orcale, nosql for a beginner. XML is fine, but i would not recommend it for costumer tables.  There are a lot of nice DBs out there. Simple: two typs: file database like oracle and server database like mysql. Have a good one.